# order by and group by with same rows in mysql select query

Tags: mysql

i have table with this structure

```
id |from_id |to_id |date

1  |1       |3     |25
2  |1       |3     |24
3  |2       |3     |28
4  |2       |3     |20
5  |2       |3     |30
```

I want to retrieve all from_id with maximum date (distinct from id with max date)

ie,

```
id |from_id |to_id |date

1  |1       |3     |25
5  |2       |3     |30
```

I have used this query

```
`select * from table where to_id=3 group by from_id order by date desc`
```

But iam getting the from_id with least date value

Comment: GROUP BY is for aggregation of results but you aren't using any aggregate functions such as COUNT or SUM. What are you expecting the GROUP BY to do?

Comment: i want to retrieve only one from_id with max date

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT tablename.*
FROM (SELECT from_id, MAX(date) dat
      FROM tablename 
      GROUP BY from_id) innerquery
  JOIN tablename
    ON  innerquery.from_id = from_id
    AND innerquery.dat = date
```

Comment: i have added one where condition also.If there is multiple users then the query will work. If it is only one user this query wont work

Comment: @THOmas Whats the `WHERE` condition?